# Changing width based on number of images and sizing images responsively in flex box

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive-images

this is my first post here. I'm doing a personal project page that displays multiple images. Some images will have captions, some images will have multiple images in one figure container, etc. However I'm running into multiple problems when trying to use flexbox to layout all the figures.

A) The images all have varying heights and widths. I'm finding it difficult to get all of the images to be proper sizes that aren't too small or too big.

B) I'm trying to get the figures to be varying, responsive width sizes based on the image widths and how many images there are. This is especially a problem when there's more than one image.

B.2) When a figure has multiple images inside, sometimes they get shoved underneath each other. This looks messy and I want the images to stay on one row.

C) Trying to get everything inside the figures centered.

I tried to solve this by doing the following...

A) I tried to use max-width/max-height, but I realized it just makes everything huge.

B & B.2) I tried to put a flexbox inside the figures but this just caused the problem shown in #fiveitems. I can't get the figure p to stay above the images like in the other figures.

C) I've tried things like text-align and I couldn't figure out what I could use to get the images centered.

A codepen with all my code

https://codepen.io/marchesn/pen/poooZLY

CSS

```
figure
{
 height: 30%;
 width: 30%;
 padding: .4em;
 border-radius: .5em;
 background-color: white;
 margin: .2em;
}
figure p
{
 height: 15%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: .1em;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #333333;
}
figcaption
{
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: .5em;
 margin-bottom: .2em;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: .3em;
 background-color: #9ad6e5;
}
figure img
{
 max-width: 35%;
 max-height: 35%;
}
#fiveitems
{
 width: auto;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row;    
}
#fiveitems p
{
 width: 100%;
}
#fiveitems img
{
 width: 40%;
}
```

I am looking for solutions that would

A) Size images to be a readable size regardless of their actual width/height.

B & B.2) Have the figures size their widths based on how many images there are inside it and to display a wide range of images at a size that makes them readable while still flexing. For example I think the #fiveitems figure should take up an entire row but the figures with one image should have a smaller width.

C) Center items inside the figures.

An image of what it should look like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG8Um.png